# Sonata Admin modify data in list view

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, form-fields

I am trying to show/edit postgis point type. I am using `creof/doctrine2-spatial` package which provides some neat functions to get X and Y values for a point. The following works fine in edit/new form so the point is listed as 'Y X' (in this case "latitude longitude").

I am not sure if this is the correct way to accomplish what I need, but it works.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('coords', 'text', array(
            'data'=>
                $this->getSubject()->getCoords()->getLatitude() . ' ' .
                $this->getSubject()->getCoords()->getLongitude()
        ));
}
```

However the problem is the list views. Because point is converted to string as `"X Y"` it prints the latitude and longitude in wrong order in list view. It prints as "longitude latitude" I am very new to sonata so I am not exactly sure how to solve the issue in list view.

Any ideas?

Update: Thanks to @kunicmarko20 I have resolved the issue:

So the file goes to `app/Resources/views/SonataAdmin/CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig`
I decided to put the file to a reasonable folder.

The contents of the template is:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <div>
        {{ object.coords.getLatitude }} {{ object.coords.getLongitude }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The code for using the template was:

```
->add('coords', null, ['template' => 'SonataAdmin/CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig']);
```

For some reason I couldn't get the `:` type path to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your list view field, you can create custom template as explained [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html#custom-template).

Example:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('yourfiled', null, ['template' => 'AppBundle:Admin:your_field_list.html.twig'])
    ;
}
```

And your template would look like:

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% block field %}
    <div>
        {{ object.longitude }} {{ object.latitude }}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The object here is your entity with all values.

Comment: I have 2 questions 1- What is the best place to put the custom template file and where is the documentation about this? 2- How do I call getLatitude() getLongitude() functions from within template?

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen I updated my answer with example, basically I have a folder Admin where I keep my templates connected to sonata

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct. However I couldnt get to find the template using the  `:` path. Here it says using colons is the old method. However I think I don't have @App defined and that also doesnt work. See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Comment: @EvrenYurtesen the `@App` syntax is only if you are using Symfony Flex, `:` syntax still works and if you have something like `AppBundle:Admin:your_field_list.html.twig` then you have to put that template in `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/your_field_list.html.twig`

Comment: I tried it all. At the location  you mention, it only works if the template path is `AppBundle::SonataAdmin/CRUD/geography_point_list.html.twig` nothing else works. This is besides the scope of this question so I made a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497251/symfony-sonata-template-path-file-not-found-and-how-directory-structures-are-arr